# .htaccess exclude specific file in webroot from URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla-sef-urls

i am running a site with joomla. It has a bunch of mod rewrite rules i don't totally understand.. as well as some kind of SEF link thing running.

i have a specific page named sched.html that i need to serve up and be completely ignored from the .htaccess.

I have tried everything i can possibly think of. including a number of recommendation from people in the Joomla forums and for the life of me i cannot get this working.

ANY help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should have that line already in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

If not, post your complete .htaccess here.

Prepend this line with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sched\.html
```

The final result should look similar to this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sched\.html
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```